# Computer doesn't turn on, motherboard or CPU?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

This morning my computer wouldn't turn on. Pressing the power button has no affect. When I turn off the switch at the back and push the power button after turning it back on it seems for about half a second that everything works: fans appear to start moving and the PSU light turns on.

This happens only for a brief moment (less than a second) and then everything turns back off. I can repeat this by turning off and on the switch at the back of the case or by unplugging the power cable out and plugging in again.

There is a small LED on the motherboard which is always on when power is connected (doesn't matter if the computer is on or off) and it is still on now.

I am trying to diagnose what is the cause of the problem PSU or motherboard. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any "beep code?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unplug everything you can possibly unplug, internally and externally, and remove all expansion cards and RAM.  So, with nothing but the main ATX power header and CPU power header (and front panel and internal speaker connections attached - see comments) attached and no RAM, if the box STILL won't power on, you probably either have a power supply or motherboard problem (the odds of a failed CPU are nil unless you've been overclocking like crazy, and if you're savvy enough to do that you shouldn't be asking this question).

If it beeps at you, which it should if you try to power it on with no RAM, reattach stuff piece by piece (starting with the RAM) to see if you can isolate a problem.

Comment: If you are listening for beep codes, make sure you actually have a case speaker attached.

Comment: @typoknig - Oops! I forget some boards have those disconnectable, haha, sorry.

Comment: tried it and still the same. I guess I will have to take it to the repairman since I don't have spares to switch and check which one it's actually is.

Comment: @user54921 - I'd give heavy odds it's a bad power supply - if you have another PC around you could swap them. (Obviously this isn't so easy with the motherboard or CPU).  Hope you get it resolved soon though - don't forget to come back and pick an answer if someone actually answered your question. ;)

Comment: What if it doesn't beep at all?

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be one of many components, but it is likely to be the RAM/CPU/PSU/Motherboard (in no particular order).

If you have access to some spare components or a someone else's similar machine, you can possibly isolate the problem yourself. The first task is to test one stick of RAM in another machine. If the RAM is good, leave it (on it's own) in your machine, leave the CPU and the PSU connected, but remove all other RAM/cards/disks/peripherals. If this allows you PC to at least 'turn-over', your RAM may well be the problem.

Likewise, if the problem remains, you need to either test each of the other main components either by proving them in another machine, or by replacing them with a spare one. Be sure to use compatible components for testing - that is, if you try to cannibalise another machine to test this one, make sure that they use similar components. The specification in your user guide should indicate this, or otherwise seek specific information from your OEM.

For your average home or business user, this might prove difficult, which is where your local independent repair shop comes in. Yes, you'll have to pay for labour on top of the replacement parts, but unless you have your own resources, you have no choice.

If you aren't confident under the bonnet of your PC, this might also be the safest option.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities, actually too many possibilities.

I believe this is a job for the repairman.

Nobody can diagnose your problem over this forum, and implementing all the suggestions you will get here will cost you much more than the repairman will.

Comment: +1 - But 'implementing all the suggestions' **may** cost you more.

Comment: There is nothing a "repairman" can do that cannot be described here. This is a place for techies.  If it costs more for him to do things than for a "repairman", then that's for him to decide. And he is welcome to be the repair man if he wants.  And any replies are not just for him, but for others with the problem, including people that tend to fix things themselves.

Comment: @barlop: OK, tell him to change the PSU. If this doesn't work then the BIOS battery, then capacitors, then RAM, followed by disk, then the motherboard. Very technical. Been there, done that. There are a zillion cases like it on SU, and my above advice was the only one that worked so many times that I'm really tired of giving it again and again. I really wish SU had a FAQ.

Comment: @barlop: Oh, and thank you for the down-vote.

Comment: @harrymc - I won't downvote because it's a cogent answer but barlop is right when he says "If it costs more for him to do things than for a "repairman", then that's for him to decide. And he is welcome to be the repair man if he wants. And any replies are not just for him, but for others with the problem, including people that tend to fix things themselves."

Comment: @Shinrai: The poster can certainly choose the answer that he likes best. I am only afraid that he doesn't have the tools or the knowledge to handle any serious problem, or he wouldn't have posted here. Operating on the computer without knowledge can do more harm than good.

Comment: @harrymc I'm sure most of us have changed a PSU and motherboard and CMOS battery, and RAM, and disk.This is a techie site where changing those things is very normal.People might come up with interesting responses though.You mention changing capacitors. That's something I haven't done!The poster is not incompetent for posting here.He does look a bit incompetent for not mentioning about changing the PSU when he hasa power issue and he should be describing what he has done2diagnose it.He may have posted and forgotten about the post.I doubt his ability but the question transcends the questioner.

Comment: btw, changing the disk can't be it!  i'd guess the bios would boot with no hard disk. I could describe what i'd do, but as you suggest, it's boring. And of course it's going to be very similar to what others have written.

Comment: @barlop: We can't in this forum teach the guy what he needs to know. He is obviously not the kind that keeps spares around. Cannibalizing another working computer for parts risks ending up with 2 broken computers. Buying everything is costly, especially the tools to analyze electronic problems. So my rule of thumb is very simple: For such a general/beginner question, recommending anything else than the repairman may do more harm than good, and I do accept some responsibility for my answers.

Comment: People make mistakes and waste money while they learn.  If he doesn't want to go down that route, then he won't.  In this case, it looks like he has seen that he doesn't have a spare PSU, he clearly doesn't want to get one, and he has decided to call a repair guy. But this site is for people repairing things themselves. He made that decision himself, not from being told to. And he made that decision after seeing the advise of changing PSU.

Comment: Anyhow, in practice, he is unlikely to lose his data if he messed about. I can't see how he would. can you?  If he was could, then he may be warned.   At worst, he won't be able to put the computer back together, and he'll call the repairman for that too, but it shouldn't be a big job for the repair man to do the lego of the other computer he might've opened and given up on.There are certain obvious non-serious risks,like humpty dumpty,take it apart and not being able to put it back together. But that's not a terrible problem.There are people that can.This guy isn't -that- dumb,he posted here.

Comment: He is clearly just somebody that isn't enthusiastic enough to have another PSU, and doesn't have knowledge. But he is logical enough to be able to ask the question, and see the technical answers, see if he is capable, and make whatever decision he wants. He did that it seems.I don't know what you have in mind for harm he could do, and I don't want to spread FUD.Perhaps there could be something in the FAQ for obvious risks you have in mind, and the fact that this is a technical site and if they think they can't then they should call a repair guy.

Comment: From my experience, if people don't understand a technical answer, they'll get scared and call a repair guy anyway.  "plug it into the USB port"  WHAAAH!!  It's if they are told "Remove that box thing from the computer" then they'd be stupidly comfortable, but nobody is doing that. And those types are aware of their limitations. They think their house will blow up if they push the wrong button on the computer. Some worry about losing data but I don't see that happening here. Any repair guy knows,people that can't fix computers don't need to be told to call a repair guy.They call.

Comment: @barlop: I agree in essence. In my experience, most questions like that don't have an accepted answer. And more often than not, the accepted answer is the one I gave.

Comment: For future readers of this question, the answer turned out to be the PSU. @barlop @harrymc - thank you for the discussion, while I did assemble this PC from scratch and have the knowledge to swap in a different PSU or motherboard I simply didn't have any spare ones so I wasn't able to determine the faulty part myself. Since there was no definitive answer as to which part was the problem I had to take it to a repairman since I was not ready to blindly buy another PSU just on a gut feeling.

Comment: Even if the questioner did take it to the repair guy, the problems with the "take it to the repair guy" answer still stand.  The technical answer that worked for him, was to change the PSU, and in comment that was a good suggestion as a first thing to try to change.Take it to the repair guy is something he can work out.If that was an answer he was looking for,then he shouldn't or wouldn't have asked here.I think best thing is for something like that to be in the FAQ.

Comment: @harrymc A good answer is the technical thing that the repair guy did to resolve it, since that is the technical solution. That technical thing may have been mentioned in a technical answer or comments in this question thread.  If you have a computer problem and ask here, and ask somebody in real life, and the person in real life tells you, and an answer here is the same as what the person in real life said. Or what the person in real life came and did with your computer. Then that is the technical answer. The answer that a super user or competent user with the resources to fix it, would do.

Comment: @barlop: Let there be peace on Earth, and let it begin with us.

Comment: @harrymc this is not a personal thing

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a failing power supply.  You might be able to buy yourself some time with the following trick:

1. Turn off the switch directly on the power supply.
2. Wait 30 seconds
3. Place one hand by the switch on the power supply and the other next to the normal power switch for the computer.
4. Turn the switch on the power supply back on
5. After about a 1/4 to 1/2 second pause press the main power switch on the computer.  This press should be distinctly separate from activating the switch on the power supply, but before the cpu fan stops moving.

Where I'm at we have a 20 machine computer lab that was last updated about 7 years ago.  The lab is (finally!) up for replacement over the Christmas break.  There are 4 machines in the lab with ailing power supplies matching the exact symptoms you describe. Rather than replace the power supplies now for machines that are schedule to be swapped out soon I've been able to use this trick to keep them going.

Note that this will only buy you a little time.  The trick actually only still works on three of my affected machines, and I don't expect that to continue much longer.  My solution in this lab is just to hand an "out of order" sign on them for the rest of the semester when they no longer boot at all.  The lab rarely needs the full capacity this late in the semester.  It's more for orientation classes early on.  But for you, the trick should allow you to use the computer while you wait for a new power supply to ship.

Comment: That's a premature diagnosis - it *could* be the PSU... or the Mobo or the RAM. I've actually seen other components produce similar results (a dodgy NIC actually). Secondly, if it is the PSU, trying to force the PSU's arm could be counter-productive - the voltage regulation circuitry (on mobo) will do it's best to protect, but nevertheless, 'jump-starting' it might not be the best idea.

Comment: What is the name of this process? I haven't heard of it before. Any web links on it?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem. Surprisingly the problem was due to loose plug. On holding the plug tightly it went away. We now switched the plug to a different point.